# When creating a new cloud composer env, is it possible to set the bucket to preexisting one?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-composer

So I already have an empty storage bucket created for this and I don't want composer to create its own bucket for the dags - I'd like to use the one already created.

It's not ideal to have it just create a random bucket and then go

```
gcloud composer environments run test-environment  --location europe-west1 variables -- --set gcs_bucket gs://my-bucket
```

I've dug around the docs but it seems you cannot go around it creating a brand new bucket every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible.

In the environment’s [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.environments#EnvironmentConfig) in Cloud Composer API, the `dagGcsPrefix` parameter is output only, you cannot set it. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage) also mentions a Cloud Storage bucket is always created along with the Composer environment, the name of the bucket is based on the environment’s region, name and a random Id.

You may want to “Star” this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118776751) for the mentioned functionality, to receive notifications whenever an update on this regard is published. You can also review or subscribe to the Cloud Composer [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#top_of_page) to be updated about recently added features.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is currently not supported in Composer.